# binding data into the List box

Tags: silverlight

how to bind the data from the text box into a List box in Silver light?
I have 5 text boxes and at the time  clicking the save button, the list box will flll with the data that displayed in the text boxes. How it will be done in silver light?

Comment: (Updated code to put data on a single line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do what you want:

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
  <ListBox x:Name="lbStrings"></ListBox>
  <TextBox x:Name="tb1" Width="50"></TextBox>
  <TextBox x:Name="tb2" Width="50"></TextBox>
  <TextBox x:Name="tb3" Width="50"></TextBox>
  <TextBox x:Name="tb4" Width="50"></TextBox>
  <TextBox x:Name="tb5" Width="50"></TextBox>
  <Button Click="Save" Content="Save" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  //lbStrings.Items.Clear(); //uncomment if needed
  lbStrings.Items.Add(
    string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}",
    tb1.Text,
    tb2.Text,
    tb3.Text,
    tb4.Text,
    tb5.Text
  ));
}
```

Comment: but how to display these 5 text boxes data in a single line of the list box?